# How to Enable Smart Search from the dashboard

Tags: administrator, smartsearch

My Joomla Dashboard lists search vs. smart search, how do I enable smart search indexing?
AND when I do, how do I see what is in the index?

I found this joomla resource: docs.joomla.org/Setting_up_automatic_Smart_Search_indexing but I was hoping to do this all from the dashboard, instead of from the command line. Any idea if that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

1. Log into your Joomla dashboard
2. Hover over Extensions in the top menu, and then click Plug-in Manager
3. Use the filter tool to search for “smart”, and then click the button to enable Content – Smart Search
4. In the top menu, hover over Components and click Smart Search
5. Click the Index icon to begin indexing your content.
6. When the indexing is complete, close the indexing window. Your page will refresh and you will see a very large list showing how your content has been indexed. Your next step will be to create a Smart Search Module so that you can begin using this feature on your site.